# Pokemon (GBA/3DS) Attaining a Living Dex Alone

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I have a 3DS with Alpha Sapphire. I am interested in getting a living dex (alone if possible).

I know I may need to get some of the older games, but is this possible - i.e. with a single 3DS, if so any guides (like how to get 3 starter pokemon from each generation legally).

Thanks.

Comment: May I know what a "living" dex is? I know what the National and Regional dex are, but I've never heard of a "living" one.

Comment: Hi, a living dex is 1 version of every pokemon collected (i.e. not released). I think that includes each version of an evolution too.

Comment: @MikeCaulfield, yep, it includes each version of the evolution

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into the Pokemon Bank. This could let you store unique pokemon or ones you have to chose between, and then with multiple run-throughs you could get all types of a given generation. It seems to be focused on Pokemon X&Y, but I think there are ways to trade from older generations up to those and then you could take advantage of it.

http://www.pokemonbank.com/en-gb/bank/

Comment: Thank you that's really useful I did not know about that so I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to obtain Pokemon from older generation is through the [Global Trade System (GTS)](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Global_Trade_System), where you can ask for or seek Pokémon even not yet registered in your Pokédex (by selecting a manual entry at end of the alphabetical options and typing out a Pokémon's name).
You can easily find every common or legendary Pokemon, except specific event Pokemon that cannot be traded.